# How do I inherit from logging.Handler to log to a GtkTextView?

Tags: python, logging

I am relatively new to Python and I'm developing my first Python GUI (slowly). One of the third-party modules I want to use uses [Python's `logging` framework](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html). I would like their logs to go to a `GtkTextView`. I know where their `logger` variable is, so can call `logger.addHandler`.

How do I inherit from `logging.Handler` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My implementation based on the source of `StreamHandler` is

```
class GtkTextViewHandler(logging.Handler):
  def __init__(self, tv):
    logging.Handler.__init__(self)
    self.tv = tv
    self.tbf = tv.get_buffer()
    self.formatter = None

  def emit(self, record):
    try:
      msg = self.format(record)
      fs  = "%s\n"
      self.tbf.insert(self.tbf.get_end_iter(), fs % msg)
      self.tv.scroll_to_iter(self.tv.get_end_iter(), 0.0, False, 0, 0)
    except:
      self.handleError(record)
```